# Linux: illegal instruction with RIP in the middle of an LEA instruction in glibc

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, crash-dumps

In redhat7.2, my program got core dump in popen function due to signal 4, Illegal instruction. but when I debug the core file, I found the Illegal instruction in rip register didn't exist. debug info as below:

```
Program terminated with signal 4, Illegal instruction.
#0  0x00007fb2f217b1f4 in popen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-105.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 zlib-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function popen@@GLIBC_2.2.5:
   0x00007fb2f217b1d0 <+0>: push   %r12
   0x00007fb2f217b1d2 <+2>: mov    %rsi,%r12
   0x00007fb2f217b1d5 <+5>: push   %rbp
   0x00007fb2f217b1d6 <+6>: mov    %rdi,%rbp
   0x00007fb2f217b1d9 <+9>: mov    $0x100,%edi
   0x00007fb2f217b1de <+14>:    push   %rbx
   0x00007fb2f217b1df <+15>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x00007fb2f217b1e3 <+19>:    callq  0x7fb2f212d340 <memalign@plt>
   0x00007fb2f217b1e8 <+24>:    test   %rax,%rax
   0x00007fb2f217b1eb <+27>:    mov    %rax,%rbx
   0x00007fb2f217b1ee <+30>:    je     0x7fb2f217b240 <popen@@GLIBC_2.2.5+112>
   0x00007fb2f217b1f0 <+32>:    lea    0xf0(%rax),%rax
   0x00007fb2f217b1f7 <+39>:    xor    %esi,%esi
```

Look at the latest two lines, 0x00007fb2f217b1f4 should between them, but it doesn't exist! why a no-exists instruction was loaded in rip register?

Comment: The address an illegal instruction was encountered at was `0x00007fb2f217b1f4`.  That's right in the middle of the `lea 0xf0(%rax),%rax` instruction and makes me think that something caused the processor to a random address.

Comment: Perhaps someone is trying to attack your system with a ret2reg or ret2code attack.  Maybe they were looking for a `jmp %rsp` 2-byte sequence or similar, but your glibc has different machine code than the system where they developed the attack.

Comment: Your wording is technically wrong. The address 0x00007fb2f217b1f4 does exist, and if you would disassemble the memory content there as x86_64 instruction, it will probably form one (or illegal opcode), but it's not like the CPU understands the original instruction boundaries, having a clue that `lea` starts at `..f0` and `xor` at `..f7`, each x86 instruction has certain "opcode" consisting of 1-15 bytes, and if you will point the CPU on the bytes in the middle, it will interpreted them as other opcode, maybe even (very likely) accidentally forming valid instruction. That `lea` has 7B opcode.

Comment: I.e. the CPU does see only normal bytes in memory (no special marker at start/end opcode), and the fetch/decode unit will advance `rip` by the amount it did use the last time to decode current instruction, so the CPU will correctly advance "per instruction" once it did start at meaningful one, but some machine code may hide different sequence of instruction at some offset start, which may be sometimes even abused by exploit writers ([ROP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming)), or when obfuscating your code, or when some bug makes your code to jump into unplanned address.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to execute at weird addresses is for a function to overwrite the saved %rip on its stack -- something like a buffer overflow can do quite nicely, but so can wild or uninitialized pointers.   When the function ‘returns’ it goes somewhere other than intended.  The purposeful version of this is the basic buffer overflow &| return-oriented-programming attacks.  But save the paranoia until it is justified.

To diagnose this, you should do a careful analysis of the stack frame this occurred in.   Can the debugger recover a meaningful stack trace?  Does the stack contain patterned data (eg. ascii strings)?

Even if the debugger can’t, it is often worthwhile to try disassembling around the values on the stack; for example if 0x123400 was on the stack, try looking at 0x1233f5 -- if it disassembles into a call instruction, you may be onto something.  Break out the intel ref, there are way too many call formats.  With a bit of effort, you can write a gdb script to automate this, or at least identify candidates.

Also look ‘beneath’ the stack, since there are often bits of call frames left intact which might hint at where it was executing.

Comment: You don't have to disassemble by hand.  Use GDB's `disas *(void**)($rsp-16), +16` to disassemble 16 bytes, with the starting address loaded from `[rsp-16]` (the stack slot below the `ret` which took you to this faulting instruction, assuming this instruction rather than an earlier one was the actual jump target).  Add +/- offsets if you want to start disassembling at a different point, or a different stack value as the base.